# Frequent very short freezes and eventual audio skips in games

Tags: windows-8, freeze, gaming

My computer has recently begun making extremely annoying short freezes during games. The freezes last for about 1-5 seconds, and sometimes the audio skips, but almost never at the same time (I might have the audio skip in-game dialogue for 10 seconds without any freezes and vise versa, might be 2 seperate problems).

The problem persists through different games, and it happens in everything from Hearthstone to League of Legends and Diablo III.

An interesting thing is, that once in-game cinematics (like the Diablo act-introductions) start, there are no problems whatsoever. Neither in audio nor visuals.

I've searches far and wide for solutions, but I haven't found anyone with this exact issue. I've defragged my harddrive and installed drivers to try to fix the problems (although the sound drivers kinda bug me, I don't really know how to get them and how to find my specific sound card)

I use a Fujitsu Lifebook A532/G21 with a GeForce GT 620M GPU, Intel i7-3632QM 2.20Ghz CPU and 6 GB RAM

Comment: What level are your video and audio setting at? Having them too high might cause this

Comment: If it were myself, I would connect a 2nd monitor to the system and have it displaying live CPU, Memory and other performance indicators in real time while you are playing the game. As soon as you notice a blip in performance, check the performance counters to see if another process is consuming resources.

Comment: When was the last time you cleaned out your cooling vents and fans? have you tested your file system and hard drive for problems yet?

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently do any updates to your computer?  If it used to work, but no longer does, something has changed.

I would go to Fujitsu's website and look for applicable software, driver, firmware updates to your laptop.  Specifically look for driver updates.

Sometimes Windows installs a driver update that is older or not as good as the manufacturers driver.  This can cause issues similar to what you are experiencing.